# Meteor for Nodejs: At it's core, is it sync or async?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, meteor

I've been researching these node frameworks. "Everybody" says "oooh you gotta use (handwaving) express!" ...and *then* [I discovered](http://nodeframework.com/) that Meteor has time and a half the github stats. Ok great, let's read about that.

In my readings, I read somewhere, and I can't refind it now, where someone said Meteor is async. From what I've read it seems to have a highly active event loop, which, if it's sync but heavily monitored by a loop like that, blocking could be mitigated. I mean just because you don't have to write callbacks doesn't mean a full-stack framework is synchronous.

So there's the question: Is the node framework Meteor built as synchronous, asynchronous, or something somewhere in-between?

Comment: Meteor is built on top of Node.JS, which is JavaScript, which is natively asynchronous. But Meteor also provides a somewhat hidden gem. It allows you to write asynchronous code in a synchronous style in order to solve some of the raging issues of asynchronous codes (for example the callback hell). It does it thanks to [fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers). So no, you don't have to write callbacks, and you can even use Meteor to [wrap your own functions](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync).

Answer (score 0):

Short version - "something somewhere in-between".

On the *client* you'd write *fully async* code, nothing special.

On the *server* side, though, Meteor uses *fibers*, as @Kyll mentioned in his comment. This abstraction layer will allow you to write your code in a *synchronous* manner.
You can find a nice and more detailed explanation [here](https://meteorhacks.com/fibers-eventloop-and-meteor).